# JPA criteria API query for date Interval

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, criteria-api

How to write the java criteria query for hibernate3.

Select * from `some_table` where  `created_at` between DATE_SUB(curdate() , INTERVAL 8 DAY) and  date_sub(curdate() ,INTERVAL 2 DAY)

```
    CriteriaBuilder builder = sessionFactory.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<MyEntity> criteria = builder.createQuery(MyEntity.class);

    Root<MyEntity> root = criteria.from(MyEntity.class);
```

Comment: If you have found my answer helpful, you should mark it as accepted, in order to help other users. Otherwise let us know why it didn't work or where it should be improved

Answer (score 3):

Using the old [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) and [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html).

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
now.add(Calendar.DATE, -8);
Date eightDaysAgo = now.getTime();
now.add(Calendar.DATE, 6);
Date twoDaysAgo = now.getTime();
Expression<Date> createdAt = root.<Date>get("created_at"); // choose the name of the property in Entity definition
Predicate predicate = builder.between(createdAt, twoDaysAgo, eightDaysAgo);
criteria.where(predicate);
```

Comment: This is not working on timestamp field in mysql . the date is stored in UTC . Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")); is also not working